# how to read and write images in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I got the problem on how to read and write the random images in the array called name[j] into another folder. Currently, i just can read and write images in the whole input directory to another directory instead of random images based on the array name [j]. i do not know how to pass the value in the array to imwrite() function.

This is my full code:

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    string homedir = "C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\Aggressive\\offline workspace\\abc";
    cerr << endl << "path =  " << homedir.c_str() << endl;

    std::string inputDirectory = "C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\Aggressive\\offline workspace\\abc";
    std::string outputDirectory = "C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder";
    DIR* directory = opendir(inputDirectory.c_str());
    struct dirent* _dirent = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int total;
    srand(time(0)); //seed random number

    vector<string> name;

    if (directory == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open Input Folder\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((_dirent = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
    {
        puts(_dirent->d_name); 
        name.push_back(_dirent->d_name); 
        printf("\n");
        i++;

        std::string fileName = inputDirectory + "\\" + std::string(_dirent->d_name);
        cv::Mat rawImage = cv::imread(fileName.c_str());
        if (rawImage.data == NULL)
        {
            printf("copied\n");
            continue;
        }
        // Add your any image filter here
        fileName = outputDirectory + "\\" + std::string(_dirent->d_name);
        cv::imwrite(fileName.c_str(), rawImage);


    }
    //name.erase(name.begin(), name.begin() + 1); 

    name.erase(name.begin(), name.begin() + 2);
    cout << "file name: " << name[16];
    total = i - 2;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "There's " << total << " files in the current directory.\n" << endl;

    cout << "Enter array size: \n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;


    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
         //generate random filename
         int index = rand() % a;
         //cout << filename[index] << endl;

         //swap random[j] with random[index]
         string temp = name[j];
         name[j] = name[index];
         name[index] = temp;
     }

     //loop through array and print value
     for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
         cout << "Random image selected:" << name[j] << endl; 
     }

    closedir(directory);
}
```

Comment: So you wanna write the selected random image to somewhere? If the ```name[j]``` which is explained as **random image selected** has the format string such ```C: \\...\image.jpg``` you can do it easily. You wanna write it to in another directory?

Comment: yes. i wanna write random image in name[j] to another directory which is C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder. please do help me.

Comment: Then read name[j]  with imread and write with imwrite?

Comment: yes. since the random image is store in name [j] so i wanna read those image and write it in the C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder. but i do not know how to do it

Comment: you can simply do it: ```Mat img = imread(name[j]);``` then write it: ```imwrite("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder\\img.jpg",img)```

Comment: i had tried it but there is an error. do i have put the code inside for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
     cout << "Random image selected:" << name[j] << endl; 
 } ? cause when i did it has an error and when i put the code outside for function it error because j is undeclared identifier.

Comment: Yes you should put inside of for loop because you are choosing ```a``` times random image also. There will be a times random image, do you want to write all those images to the directory? If yes, you should put advised codes to for loop and change the written name in every loop

Comment: so i need to put the advised code into new for loop but i do not catch the part of change written name in every loop. what do you mean by that? sorry i'm new to this programming. if it not too much, could you give me an example for me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `name[j]` is a string in the format of `C:\\...\\img.jpg` you can read those images in each loop cycle and write them to your desired directory.

```
   for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
         cout << "Random image selected:" << name[j] << endl; 
         // name[j] should be in the directory format like "C:\\...\\img.jpg"
         //Then read this image
         Mat img = imread(name[j]);

         //Then write to desired directory in every loop you need to change the name to avoid writing on the same name.
         string written_directory = "C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder\\img" + std::to_string(j) + ".jpg";
         imwrite(written_directory,img);                  
     }
```

Comment: if my image save as 2. jpg means that i need just need to string written_directory = "C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder\\" + std::to_string(j) + ".jpg"; ? but now i have an error OpenCV(3.4.10) Error: Assertion failed (!_img.empty()) in cv::imwrite, file C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp, line 759

Comment: Then there can be 2 reasons: 1 is written directory not exist. 2 is your image(name[j] doesnt exist

Comment: i tried to read the whole file in C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\Aggressive\\offline workspace\\abc and write it in the C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\folder and it successful. that means my path is correct. when i did the random filename, i already check that the file is existing in the folder abc. And now i do not understand exactly  whats the problem. Btw, thank you for help me. :)

Comment: how about i want to write filename based on its original name? for example, in name[j] has a file 2.jpg then when i write based on the suggested code, it will save my image as img0.

Comment: Then u need to play with the namej string in loop, and get the last part of string which consist the original name then add it to written directory string